# How to replace similar cyrillic and english characters

Tags: java, string

I have a text box where the user can input the string with letters and numbers in Java, i.e.

String inputString="Аs87df56VСХ6ВР";

And also the user can forget to switch the language and input this string using cyrillic alphabet, because there are similar characters in cyrillic and english alphabets: **ABCEHKMOPTX**

My question is: how to find and replace cyrillic letters in the input string?

Comment: What do you mean by cyrillic letters? Post an input along with expected output.

Comment: visually there is no difference: the user input "ABC" in cyrillic and I want to convert it in "ABC" in English

Comment: The problem with this is for example cyrillic "P" equals "R" in latin, not "P" in latin, are you sure you want to replace all cyrillic R to latin P?

Comment: I want to replace only visually similar characters, i.e. cyrillic "P" should equal latin "P"

Comment: But your "Cyrillic" chars are actually Latin chars. Can you post the correct code points please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`replaceChars()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceChars(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) utility method from the [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#) class of the Apache common-lang library.

```
str = StringUtils.replaceChars(str, "АВЕЅZІКМНОРСТХШѴУ", "ABESZIKMHOPCTXWVY");
```

I used actual Cyrillic chars in this code (so you can copy-paste it) and added a couple of moderately similar letters too.

Comment: @Alex78191 OK. I added `У`.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to use a HashMap to keep all the mappings and then replace them like shown in the snippet

```
HashMap<Character, String> mapping = new HashMap<>();
mapping.put('\u0410', "A");
mapping.put('\u0412', "B");
mapping.put('\u0421', "C");
mapping.put('\u0415', "E");
mapping.put('\u041D', "H");
mapping.put('\u041A', "K");
mapping.put('\u041C', "M");
mapping.put('\u041E', "O");
mapping.put('\u0420', "P");
mapping.put('\u0422', "T");
mapping.put('\u0423', "Y");
mapping.put('\u0425', "X");

// String contains latin+cyrillic characters
String input = "AАBВCСEЕHНKКMМOОPРTТYУXХ";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());
for (Character c : input.toCharArray()) {
    if (c > 'Z') {
        System.out.printf("add latin: %s  for cyrillic: %s%n", mapping.get(c), c);
        sb.append(mapping.get(c));
    } else {
        System.out.printf("add latin: %s%n", c);
        sb.append(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A slow but simple solution would be to make 2 strings with only chars you want to replace:

```
String yourtext = " this is a sample text";
String cyrillic = "ABHOP..."
String latin = "ABNOP..."
for(int i = 0;i<yourtext.length();i++){
    for(int j = 0;j<latin.length();j++){
        if( latin.charAt(j) == yourtext.charAt(i)){
        yourtext = changeCharInPoistion(i,cyrillic.charAt(j), yourtext);
        }
    }
}

public String changeCharInPosition(int position, char ch, String str){
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
charArray[position] = ch;
return new String(charArray);
}
```